# How to convert spaces into new line using perl?

Tags: perl

---

I have the following input which is stored in single scalar variable named as $var1.

Input(i.e stored in $var1)

```
Gain Dead_coverage Export_control Functional_coverage Function_logic top dac_decoder Datapath System_Level Black_DV Sync_logic temp1 temp2 temp3 temp4 temp5 temp6 123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263
```

Expected output:

```
Gain 
Dead_coverage 
Export_control 
Functional_coverage 
Function_logic 
top 
dac_decoder 
Datapath 
System_Level 
Black_DV 
Sync_logic 
temp1 
temp2 
temp3 
temp4 
temp5 
temp6 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

My code:

I had tried the following regular expression.

```
$var1=tr{\s}{\n};
```

The above regular expression not brings my expected output.

Note:the numbers may range upto n numbers and the character may starts or ends with capital or lower case.Whatever i need to bring like the expected output.For that which regular expression can i use it.

Requirements:

```
1.split space into new line.
2.for numbers(i.e 123456789101112.....) it should be considered as  follows
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
.
.
.
so on,...

After digit 9 the other numbers should be considered as double digit.
```

Answer (score 1):

`tr` is a transliteration. That only works with individual characters, not patterns. You need to use `s///` with the `/g` modifier.

```
$var1 =~ s/\s/\n/g;
```

You can also do this with `split` and `join`.

```
$var1 = join "\n", split / /, $var1;
```

It shouldn't make a difference in terms of performance, even if there are *a lot* of strings.

Comment: @ssr1012 I didn't see that. True. But weird input.